# When question is considered "read".

Tags: discussion

What are the flags in my browser which determine whether a question appears on the main list of questions in SE? For example, one run I read the titles and perhaps open a new window for one of the questions. Close question browser window, close main SE question window. Go to another webpage, go back re-opening main window of SE. What have I missed and why. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no notion of a "read" questions, beyond the basic feature that visited links are colored differently. (How this is handled exactly will depend on the settings of your browser.)

What appears on "the main list" (though there are really several main lists) are basically a list of the current questions in the respective category. 
The most common would likely be [the active tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=active), that is a list of questions sorted by last modification.

In particular, this list is the same for all users regardless their prior activity. (To be precise, it is possible to follow or ignore certain tags and this will affect the list, but it will still not depend on prior activity.)

What you miss is the turn over that happened in the interim.